# How get textbox value in modal using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get textbox value which i entered in textbox after run the modal but when i alert the value its showing me null.I have used this code

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="barcode" name="barcode" value="">
</div>
<input type='button' onclick='getSet()' value='Check Function' />

<script>
  function getSet() {
    var a = document.getElementById('barcode').value;
    alert(a);
  }
</script>
```

and use this function on button click.Please guide me.How can i fix this error

Comment: It alerts you `null`, or triggers an error message?

Comment: it alerts me null

Comment: It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/1muceb4o/

Comment: but when i use this in modal its showing me null

Comment: Do you have only one(!) element with the ID "barcode"?

Comment: yes i have just one element of this name

Comment: in my case it is getting value from parent window in modal,but when i am getting modal's textbox value its showing null

Comment: try to console the element you target. then you can check the value. is the same as @jan said may you are targeting the wrong element.

Comment: I have check this,the id fine ok

Comment: What do mean when you say "parent window"? Does the modal display an iframe or something? Or is it loaded via AJAX?